# Why I cannot effectively mock function with unittest.mock.patch?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write UT for function with other function mocked. Both lies in the same module. It appears that **unittest.mock.patch()** call passes without error but doesn't mock anything so I'm getting exception in the example code. So, my question is: How to mock **foo** with **unittest.mock.patch** ?

```
import unittest
import unittest.mock

def foo():
        raise Exception("not implemented")

def bar():
        foo()

class UT(unittest.TestCase):

        def testBar(self):
                with unittest.mock.patch('mock_test.foo',spec=True) as mock_foo:
                        bar()    # <- original foo is called here

unittest.main()
```

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: You probably just want `patch('foo')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to use `unittest.mock.patch` and patch the `foo` returns. See the comments in the example:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch


def foo():
        raise Exception("Not implemented")


def bar():
        return foo()


class UT(unittest.TestCase):

        def testBar(self):
            # foo is mocked to raise a ValueError and catch it during the test
            with patch('__main__.foo', side_effect=ValueError):
                with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
                    bar()

            # foo is mocked to raise and exception and catch it during the test
            with patch('__main__.foo', side_effect=Exception):
                with self.assertRaises(Exception):
                    bar()

            # foo is mocked to return 1
            with patch('__main__.foo', return_value=1):
                self.assertEqual(bar(), 1, "Should be equal to 1")

            # foo is mocked to return an object
            with patch('__main__.foo', return_value={}):
                self.assertIsInstance(bar(), dict, "Should be an instance of dict")


unittest.main()
```

Output:

```
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```

For more informations, please visit the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)

Comment: Thanks! Of course '__main__' is the core that I missed.